# php | update current page only when db updates using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a website that the user can pay by sending items to my bot in steam.

When he does so a callback.php page is triggered that updates the Database with the new sum of money the user has.

I want the current page of the website that the user is in to update only when the database is updated showing that the transaction was received.

what I tried doing is using Ajax with a setInterval every 5 sec to an update.php page that checks if the database has changed and it's working but with a lot of users connect at the same time a connection to the database every 5 sec is too much especially if the database isn't going to be updated most of the time.

Is there a more efficient way to do this ?

My code :

```
    function calldb()
{
      $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType :"html",
   url: 'update.php',
   success:function(data)
   {    if (data="YES")
        $("#status").html('<b>Transaction recieved</b>');

   }
   });
}
setInterval(calldb(),5000);
```

Comment: Can use websockets which will lessen load on server

Comment: Note that your syntax is wrong. You houldn't invoke `calldb`. Should be `setInterval(calldb,5000);`

Comment: it's the first time I hear about websockets so I am going to educate myself about them first.